# Serverless Phone Verification with Twilio Verify and Twilio Functions error

Tags: javascript, twilio

I am trying to implement a project in Vuejs with this https://www.twilio.com/code-exchange/one-time-passcode-verification-otp. I deployed my functions through this.

I have a custom vuejs app that I’m using this in a form with.

*Here is my front end function*

```
verifyNumber() {

  var auMobilePrefix = “+61”;
  var m = this;
  m.mobileNumber = ‘’;
  m.mobileNumber = auMobilePrefix.concat(this.finalModel.mobile);
  // console.log(m.mobileNumber);

    const code = this.vcode;

    const data = new URLSearchParams();
    data.append(“to”, m.mobileNumber);
    data.append(“verification_code”, code);

    fetch(“https://verify-xxxx-xxxxx.twil.io/check-verify”, {
      method: ‘POST’,
      body: data
    })

    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      if (json.success) {
        console.log(json.message);
      } else {
        console.log(json.message);
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

After I validate the code. I get the following error in console:

Verify-xxxx-xxxxx.twil.io/check-verify:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

MultiStepVerification.vue?280d:214 The requested resource /Services/VAxxxxxxx/VerificationCheck was not found

How do I resolve this issue?

**Update**

https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/api/verification-check

This is actually the intended behaviour.

Twilio deletes the verification SID once it’s:

- expired
- approved
- when the max attempts to check a code have been reached

Under the verification service logs I noticed that the Status for my tests were Approved.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the Twilio Helper Library version, to make sure it is current?

[twilio-node changelog](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node/blob/main/CHANGES.md)

You can manually add a Twilio helper library version to your Twilio Function NPM Dependencies to override the older version used by default, which is currently 3.29.2.

[Displays Node Version and Twilio Helper Library Version](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart/serverless-functions-displays-node-version)

Comment: I updated to 3.50.0. But it turns out this is actually the intended behaviour. Thanks Alan!